# if Statment is executed if variable is null

Tags: java, if-statement

Why is if executed if the user is null?

System out user = null

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {
        String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
        System.out.println(user);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Falscher Benutzer oder Passwort");
    }
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing if the session is not null. This is true and the code in the if condition is executed. If you want to execute the code only if the attribute user is set, than you have to change it:

```
if (session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```